# Executing code when a tab is shown

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

I want to do some operations on a **tab** when it is shown.

Example:

```
textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
textBox3.SelectionStart = textBox3.Text.Length;
textBox3.ScrollToCaret();
textBox2.SelectionStart = textBox2.Text.Length;
textBox2.Focus();
```

Where should I place that code that it's done properly?

The events **tabControl1_Selecting**, **tabControl1_Selected** and **tabPage2_Enter** do not work beause they occur before the tab is shown.

I know that first the tab must be shown and then the code must be executed.

Comment: How about catching the `Enter` event of the `tabPage` instead of the `tabControl` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try it in `SelectedIndexChanged` event ,

```
private void yourTabControl1_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) { 
           textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;
           textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
           textBox3.SelectionStart = textBox3.Text.Length;
           textBox3.ScrollToCaret();
           textBox2.SelectionStart = textBox2.Text.Length;
           textBox2.Focus(); 
                }
```